# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -4

Tags: android, media-player, runtimeexception, visualizer

I am getting below error when running app on API  16.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -4
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -4
                      at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:199)
                      at xyz.activity.AudioPreviewActivity.setupVisualizerFxAndUI(AudioPreviewActivity.java:83)
                      at xyz.activity.AudioPreviewActivity.initAudio(AudioPreviewActivity.java:60)
                      at xyz.activity.AudioPreviewActivity.onCreate(AudioPreviewActivity.java:40)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Error line-

```
mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
```

Code

```
private void setupVisualizerFxAndUI() {

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(filePath));
    mMediaPlayer
            .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });

    mMediaPlayer.start();
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(
                    new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
                        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                                                          byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                            mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
                        }

                        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                                                     byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                        }
                    }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
        }
```

I already have added below permissions in manifest-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Log the value of mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId() please

Comment: @NickCardoso value of mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId() is 5

Comment: That seems like it would be valid, but you get the same value every time? That's not what I'd expect

Answer (score 3):

`-4` Means you gave a bad parameter. Although getAudioSessionId can be called in any state, have you called `prepare` and `start` on the MediaPlayer you are using, to ensure it has a good state before attempting to visualise?

You may also need to add the `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` permission when using the Visualiser this way and `android.permission.INTERNET` if the audio source isn't local

Comment: i am using `mMediaPlayer.start();` and permission also ..check out my updated question with mediaplayer code

Answer (score 3):

Add a runtime permission for api 23 and above.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            int hasAudioPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
            int hasInternetPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();


      if (hasAudioPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
            }

            if (hasInternetPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
            }

            if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
                requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), PERMISSION);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely you have something [bad in the configuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#ERROR_BAD_VALUE) of the Visualizer, double check the content in your `setupVisualizer` method. Please refer to [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598094/android-cannot-initialize-visualizer-engine-error-4).

Comment: Its working in other versions emulator..only if i check in emulator of api 16 then its not working

Comment: i am using      `mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(filePath));`

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but still.

**The problem has nothing to do with permissions**, as you stated, you targeted API 16 and you added permissions in your manifest, so [A.N.T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43147298/5550161)'s answer doesn't even make sense.

**The problem is that you are calling the `Visualizer` before `MediaPlayer` is prepared.**

---

You can fix this by calling it after `mMediaPlayer` is prepared, like this:

```
private void setupMediaPlayer(String filePath) {

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(filePath));

    //Check when MediaPlayer is completed
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    //Check when MediaPlayer is prepared
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            //MediaPlayer is prepared and playback can now start
            startPlaying();

        }
    });

}
```

Once `mMediaPlayer` is prepared:

```
private void startPlaying() {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    //Now we can call the Visualizer
    createVisualizer();
}
```

Then you can call `Visualizer` like this:

```
private void createVisualizer() {
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] waveform, int samplingRate) {
            mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
        }

        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
            //Do something you like
        }

    }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);

}
```